# Add click ripple to clickable ClickableSpan

Tags: android

Thank you for your time.

Does anyone know where/how to implement a ripple effect instead of highlight effect for clickable span in android.

Either via class extension or by some other means.

Simply by setting a BG color using the pain object and a relevant drawable is not woking for me.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, you have found some solution? I have that's problem!

Comment: I never did solve this with a background ripple effect, but I was able to style the span text a different colour etc.

Comment: I just needed the ripple effect, but I will forget it's! Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoArmando, were you able to solve the above problem

Comment: Has android not included a means to add ripple interactions to UI elements yet? How uncanny.